# python3 на ubuntu server 16.04 выводит в latin1

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, django, кодировка, utf-8

На Ubuntu server 16.04 в python3 не печатается текст с русскими буквами (utf8).

Я так понимаю, потому что в ubuntu

```
>>>print(sys.stdout.encoding)
ISO-8859-1
```

а на винде

```
>>>print(sys.stdout.encoding)
'UTF-8'
```

Но самое интересное, если на винде создать csv файл (он сохраняется в ANSI) и распарсить его на сервере ubuntu, то он будет выдавять крякозабли в latin1(ISO-8859-1).

Конечно, можно сделать `.encode("cp1252").decode("cp1251")` для каждого русского текста, но так совсем не прикольно. Тем более на винде тот же код выдаст ошибку, получается один и тот же файл будет разным для винды и убунты (а это уже совсем не прикольно).

Вообщем, я что-то не понимаю, не знаю как правильно сделать. Можете что-нибудь подсказать? Уже перечитал много чего про кодировки, вроде все понимаю, но что делать в этой ситуации не знаю. Может можно как-то настроить sys.stdout.encoding на ubuntu?

Основная моя задача из csv файла созданного на windows добавить данные в postresql на ubuntu server 16.04. На данные момент без функции `.encode("cp1252").decode("cp1251")` для каждого русского текста в базу сохраняется все в latin1(ISO-8859-1). И еще хотелось бы, чтобы на сервере ubuntu в python файлах можно было бы писать `print("Привет!")`

Кто что может посоветовать?

Comment: `$ LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 python -c 'import sys;print(sys.stdout.encoding)'`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, print так правильно выводит, но если я пытаюсь достать записи из CSV и записать в postgresql, то записывается неправильно

Comment: `$ iconv -f cp1251 -t utf-8 input.file > output.file`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо

Comment: кодировка csv файла **никак** не связана с кодировкой стандартного вывода python или  с кодировкой используемой в PostgreSQL (три кодировки, которые могут быть независимо изменены). *"как импортировать csv файл c Винды (сохранённый в cp1251 кодировке) в PostgreSQL"* и "почему у меня не работает `print('Привет!')`"* это независимые вопрос (можете их как отдельные Stack Overflow вопросы задать).